# Sorting assoc array by duplicate value on assoc array

Tags: php, sorting, php-7

I would like to sort an array by duplicate value of a specific key  :
I dont want to remove duplicate item but i just need to sort my array by duplicate

for exemple i have this array :

```
$data = array(
    array(
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Bruce Wayne",
        "city" => "Gotham",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Diana Prince",
        "city" => "Gotham",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "name" => "Speedy Gonzales",
        "city" => "New Mexico",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),    
    array(
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "Diana Prince",
        "city" => "New Mexico",
        "gender" => "Female"
    ),

    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "Bruce Wayne",
        "city" => "Gotham",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),
);
```

what should i have as a response is :

```
$data = array(
        "id" => 1,
        "name" => "Bruce Wayne",
        "city" => "Gotham",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 5,
        "name" => "Bruce Wayne",
        "city" => "Gotham",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 2,
        "name" => "Diana Prince",
        "city" => "Gotham",
        "gender" => "Male"
    ),
   array(
        "id" => 3,
        "name" => "Diana Prince",
        "city" => "New Mexico",
        "gender" => "Female"
    ),
    array(
        "id" => 4,
        "name" => "Speedy Gonzales",
        "city" => "New Mexico",
        "gender" => "Male"
    )
);
```

In my code I have an assoc array i nedd to sort it by a given key without removing duplicate value that all what i need 
How can I do this ?
thank you

Comment: Try with that: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7091144/ordering-php-arrays-based-on-duplicate-values

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use multidimensional sorting through `array_mutlisort()` combined with `array_column()` (to fetch which column is the basis for sorting). This function is by reference, so you don't need to assign the result back to something.

```
$data = array(...);
array_multisort(array_column($data, "name"), SORT_ASC, $data);
print_r($data);
```

- Live demo at https://3v4l.org/1n8fW

Answer (score 0):

You can use `usort`

```
function compare($a, $b)
{
   if ($a["name"] == $b["name"]) {
    return 0;
   }
  return ($a["name"] < $b["name"]) ? -1 : 1;
}

usort($data,"compare");
```